# Java - ByteArrayOutputStream replacement but only for 1 value

Tags: java, client-server, outputstream

Is it possible to somehow truncate this in the second case because I don't need an Array. 
This is my code:

```
    public static byte[] createHandshakeMessage(String host, int port, int protocol) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(buffer);
    handshake.writeByte(0x00); //packet id for handshake

    //Fields->
    //some code...

    return buffer.toByteArray();
}
public static byte createClient(){
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();//is there a replacement for this?

    DataOutputStream handshake = new DataOutputStream(buffer);
    handshake.writeByte(0x00); //packet id for login start

    String offlineSession = "Username";

    //Fields->
    writeString(handshake, offlineSession, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    return buffer.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple `OutputStream.write(b)`.